# Limit editing capabilities to one page

Tags: pages, user-roles, editor

I have one user on WP website. I want to give him editor role because he need to edit pages and as I see - [edit_pages capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_pages) requires user to be at least editor. The problem is that i want to limit list of pages and posts that he can edit. How it can be done?

Comment: This kind of question has been asked numerous times, such as [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191658/allowing-user-to-edit-only-certain-pages) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/allowing-users-to-edit-only-their-page-and-nobody-elses) or even [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29009/how-to-assign-specific-users-the-capability-to-edit-specific-pages-posts-cus). Will any of those help you get started?

Comment: thank you - this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172282/16650 helped me!

Comment: Great to hear! It's funny though, isn't it, that the 'correct' answer linked from the 'duplicate answer' above suggested a plugin as a solution! Blasphemy on SO, but somehow it was deemed to be the correct answer!